# Which is the correct way of writing years - '90-'91 or '90-91?

Tags: apostrophe, dates

While writing years (like 1990 to 1991) with apostrophes, should the apostrophe come before both the years (as in '90-'91) or just the first one (as in '90-91)?

Comment: I wouldn't bother with the apostrophes at all. Their only purpose is to save space, but ***1990-91*** is the same number of characters anyway - [***and it's much more common***.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%2790-%2791%2C1990-91&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%2790%20-%20%2791%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C1990-91%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: ...but if you *insist* on using apostrophes (a perfectly "valid" stylistic choice), it's [pretty much 50-50](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%2778-%2779%2C%2778-79&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%2778%20-%20%2779%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%2778%20-%2079%3B%2Cc0) whether to repeat it in such contexts.